# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate

> ```
> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
> ```
>
> users is not mapped [SELECT email, id
>   FROM users WHERE email='dsdd@dds.com'
>   AND password='asasas']

```
public ILogin authenticate(Login login) {
        System.out.println(login);
        System.out.println(login.getEmail());
        String query = "SELECT email, id FROM users WHERE email='"
        + login.getEmail() + "' AND password='" + login.getPassword() + "'";
        results = getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
        System.out.println(results);
        return null;
}
```

I have a Login Bean class... here it follows.

```
package 

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Login {
      public Login(){}
        private Long id = null;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public Login(String email, String password)
        {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;

        }
}
```

My application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" default-autowire="byName" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->

<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.intermedix"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.intermedix.domain.Login</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>   

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SELECT email, id FROM users

What is "users"?  There is nothing in your config or code called "users", so Hibernate has no idea what you're talking about.

Secondly, your `Login` class is not annotated with `@Entity`, so Hibernate is likely ignoring it.

So add the annotation, and most likely change your query to:

> SELECT email, id FROM Login

Comment: But my table name is users should i change it to Login

Comment: @theJava: No. HQL should refer to entities and properties, not tables and columns.

Comment: @theJava: By annotating `Login` with `@Table(name="users")`. How were you expecting Hibernate to know about the `users` table if you don't tell it?

Comment: then what is @Entity in all should i add @Entity and @Table(name="users") above the Login Class

Answer (score 8):

Even if it does not belong to your question:

**Don't use Hibernate/JPA in this way (String concatination) !**:

```
String query = "SELECT email, id FROM users AS u WHERE email='"+ login.getEmail() + "' AND password='" + login.getPassword() + "'";
```

Instead use HQL like prepared statements:

```
createQuery(
   "SELECT l FROM login WHERE l.email=:email AND l.password=:password")
   .setParameter("login",login.getEmail())
   .setParameter("password",login.getPassword());
```

If you do it in "your style" you will have lot of fun with SQL Injections!

Next: read the hibernate reference about HQL, for me it looks like you are writing SQL instead of HQL.

Answer (score 2):

Looks obvious to me : "users is not mapped..."

Either you didn't map the Users table, or you have it incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Login {
```

You actually need to annotate Login class since you say (`<property name="annotatedClasses">`) that in application-context.xml for example like this.

```
@Column(name="password")
public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Form3A where FAC_ID=?",FAC_ID);
```

HERE Form3A is name of class and config file is

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>org.fbis.models.Form3A</value>
</list>
</property>
```