# Error: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Updating the entire post.

```
public Login authenticate(Login login) {
        String query = "SELECT 1 FROM Login AS l WHERE l.email=? AND l.password=?";
        Object[] parameters = { login.getEmail(), login.getPassword() };
        List resultsList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query,parameters);
        if ( resultsList.size() == 1 ) {
        results = (Login)resultsList.get(0);
        System.out.println(results);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error dude.... ");
        // error no entity or mutiple entities
        }
        return results;
}
```

I now return Login Objects.

```
private void checkLogin() {
        form.commit();

        Login newUser = new Login();
        newUser = ilogin.authenticate(loginbean);
        System.out.println("Its Null Value" + newUser);
        if (newUser == null) {
            getWindow().showNotification("Login failed", LOGIN_ERROR_MSG,
                    Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            System.out.println(newUser);
            getApplication().setUser(newUser);
        }
    }
```

When there is no matching email, i get there is no such user and also this statement does get printed out. `System.out.println("Its Null Value" + newUser);`

But when there is a email and password matching. I get weird error.

> Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   com.intermedix.domain.Login
>           at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:507)
>           at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1154)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:193)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1094)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:590)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:266)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:476)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>           at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>           at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   com.intermedix.domain.Login
>           at com.intermedix.services.LoginService.authenticate(LoginService.java:31)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:301)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>           at $Proxy32.authenticate(Unknown Source)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog.checkLogin(LoginDailog.java:106)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog.access$0(LoginDailog.java:102)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog$1.buttonClick(LoginDailog.java:52)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:487)
>           ... 26 more

**Updating**

My Login bean class

```
package com.intermedix.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Login {
      public Login(){}
        private Long id = null;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public Login(String email, String password)
        {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;

        }
}
```

and also i updated according to raplh the query.

Comment: you are trying to fetch only two attribute and casting in whole obj

Comment: can u just light me out on what to edit

Comment: What does LoginService.authenticate line 32 look like?

Comment: updated the entire class

Comment: What is ILogin and what does it extend? Reading between the lines, I'm assuming that you should be returning a different object, not the email and id as in the select. I'm assuming there is an object you can return which does in fact implement ILogin and thus is castable to LoginService.

Comment: It looks like Login is not a properly mapped hibernate class. Can you post that ? And please add this line "System.out.println(resultsList.get(0).getClass().toString());" before the results = (Login)resultsList.get(0); and show what it prints.

Comment: hava a look at my original post: i have corrected a mistake in the query and some java-syntax stuff

Comment: I updated on your post... @Toader its class java.lang.Integer

Comment: Damn Courier font :))) i'll update my answer with a proper solution then :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question [org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645924/org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexception/), I strongly assume that Login is a mapped object.

In this case you do not need to do the mapping between the query result and the object by hand, if you use Hibernate in the correct way:

**corrected** (i have forgot the "AS l" part of the query)

```
   List results = createQuery(
     "SELECT l FROM login AS l WHERE l.email=:email AND l.password=:password")
     .setParameter("email",login.getEmail())
     .setParameter("password",login.getPassword()).list();
   if (results.isEmpty()) {
     //.. login failed
   } else if (result.size() > 1) {
     throw new SomethingWrongException();
   } else {
     Login login = (Login) results.get(0);
   }
```

Comment: Of course you could optimze the query by not loading the object, instead only count the matching entites: 0 == login failed, 1 == pass,  >= 2 == you should use unique constraints

Comment: @theJava -- I do not understand? -- Did it work now? -- you need: String query = "FROM Login WHERE email=? AND password=?";

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method createQuery(String) is undefined for the type LoginService
 - List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized

Answer (score 6):

When you execute a query like

> SELECT email, id FROM Login WHERE email=? AND password=?

You're asking Hibernate to give you the specific properties `email` and `id` from the `Login` entity. Hibernate will then give you the results as a list of arrays, with each list item representing the `[email, id]` array.

If you just want to query for all `Login` entities that match your criteria, then do this:

> FROM Login WHERE email=? AND password=?

And then your result list will contain `Login` objects.

But as to why you're trying to cast to `LoginService`, I haven't a clue. You're confusing a number of different Hibernate concepts and trying to mash them all together.

I don't mean to sound unhelpful, but I think you really need to go and read the Hibernate docs properly, and get a better grasp of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing this:

```
 return (LoginService) results.get(0);
```

with this:

```
 return (Login) results.get(0);
```

Assuming that `Login` is a properly mapped hibernate entity it should work.

you should also change this line

```
String query = "SELECT 1 FROM Login AS l WHERE l.email=? AND l.password=?";
```

to

```
String query = "SELECT login FROM Login AS login WHERE login.email=? AND login.password=?";
```

Also keep in mind that @Ralph's suggestion is a very good one for how to parametrize queries. You should do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

With your updated question:

Update your query:

```
String query = "SELECT l FROM Login AS l WHERE l.email=? AND l.password=?";
```

And please read the manual:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.intermedix.domain.Login i get this error after updating u r code

Comment: Please post the compleste stack trace, and mark the line in which the exception occures.